# Multiplication of two noise

Tags: noise, power-spectral-density, autocorrelation

I have a question on the multiplication of  two noise.

Suppose I have two noise $n_1[n]$ and $n_2[n]$. I only know their power spectral density $N_1[k]$ and $N_2[k]$. How can I get  $N_3[k]$, where $N_3[k]$ is the power spectral density of $n_3[n] = n_1[n] n_2[n]$. Let's first assume $n_1[n]$ and $n_1[n]$ are independent.

I am thinking to first calculate the auto-correlation $R(n_1[n] n_2[n])$. Then $$N_3[k] = F(R(n_1[n] n_2[n]))=F(R(n_1[n])R(n_2[n]))=F(R(n_1[n]))*F(R(n_1[n])),$$ where $F()$ represents Fourier transform. But we only know the amplitude of information of $F(R(n_1[n]))$ and $F(R(n_2[n]))$ through $N_1[k]$ and $N_2[k]$. That is, we do not have the phase information. How can we calculate $N_3[k]$?

Could somebody help on this?

Comment: If $N_3$ is the power spectral density of $n_3$, then it will be calculated as the Fourier transform of the autocorrelation function of $n_3$.  There is no phase information.

Comment: @PeterK. Correct, but in order to calculate $N_3[k]$, I feel like I need phase information of $F(R(n_1[n]))$ and $F(R(n_2[n]))$  to do the convolution. But $N_1[k]$ nad $N_2[k]$ only give me information about the maginitude

Comment: You _cannot_ calculate the power spectral density (nor the autocorrelation function) of the term-by-term product of the two processes from the information you have.

Comment: As noted above: these are random processes! In surprised to read that you *know* the PSD; it's very likely that you actually only estimate it based on a simple observation of a realization of these processes. I think you should be far more careful with your terms here.

Comment: At any rate, the way a PSD is calculated or estimated doesn't allow to get phase information. Hence, you can not get them back. Hence, unless you either come up with a stochastic phase model or the original observation, you can't solve this.